# Droppable items not displaying hoverClass if they are shown during drag operation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I know the title is confusing, but the problem is easily reproduced.

I have some elements on my page that are droppable (jQueryUI), and the hoverClass shows when they are being dragged over. However, I have some hidden elements that are sometimes shown during the drag, and then do not respond with their hoverClass as they should.

I have a jsFiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ControlFreak/CsXpL/) that shows this happening, however, if you continue to drag the div around eventually the listItems start to show their hoverClass. However, on my site this never happens ... the hoverClass never appears on the newly shown items.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Row1</li>
    <li>Row2</li>
    <li>Row3<span id="More">MORE...</span></li>
    <li style="display: none;">Row4</li>
    <li style="display: none;">Row5</li>
</ul>
<div id="DragMe">DragMe!</div>
```

CSS

```
#DragMe {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: RGBA(255,255,255,0.5);
}
.DragOver {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#More {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('#DragMe').draggable({
    cursorAt: {top: 50, left: 50}
});

$('li').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'DragOver'
});

$('#More').droppable({
    over: function() {
        $('li').show();
    }
});
```

Is there something I can change to get this working correctly?

Answer (score 14):

I guess jQuery UI has a bug working with hidden elements that are droppables. A workaround could be to work with opacity:

HTML

```
...
<li class="hidden">Row4</li>
<li class="hidden">Row5</li>
...
```

CSS

```
.hidden{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JS

```
$('#More').droppable({
    over: function() {
        $('li.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/CsXpL/2/

**EDIT**

You owe me an ice cold beer! Draggable has following option: `refreshPositionsType` saying:

`If set to true, all droppable positions are calculated on every mousemove. Caution: This solves issues on highly dynamic pages, but dramatically decreases performance.`.

Link: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-refreshPositions

So solution is:

```
$('#DragMe').draggable({
    cursorAt: {top: 50, left: 50},
    refreshPositions: true
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/CsXpL/9/

Comment: The problem here is that the hidden elements are often between shown elements, and opacity isn't enough since the other elements would need to shift down to allow the new ones to come in. If the hidden elements were always at the bottom this would work fine.

Comment: If OP didn't get you that beer, I surely will. refreshPositions: true worked for me!

Comment: @Simon Ditto ! If you are in ever in SF i will def buy you a beer ! Thank you !!!!!

Comment: @wmitchell I will get back to you next time in US!